# Spring MVC / Spring Roo Custom controller that returns JPA Query Data In JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-roo

I'm new to Spring MVC and Roo, I was able to deploy a Roo project very easily. I created my data model and deployed it in a mysql database with their Json controllers. Everything is working perfectly and I can pull my data from my database via restful commands. However I'm having difficulty understanding how to create my own custom JSON controller where I can grab specific data from a query I define in one of my tables.

I have three tables; Patient, Doctor, and Careteam that connects the two.

The Careteam table holds all the records which associates a patient with many docotor and doctors with many patients.

The goal of the controller is to pass it a parameter PatientID, and then

Select Doctors from Careteam where  PatientID = PatientID;

The query will return me all the doctors for that PatientID and then wraps it in JSON so I get grab it through a restful command.

Here is my code:

Careteam.java

```
package com.medroid.domain;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.json.RooJson;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJson
public class Careteam {

    /**
     */
    @ManyToOne
    private Patient patient;

    /**
     */
    @ManyToOne
    private Doctor doctor;
}
```

Doctor.java

```
package com.medroid.domain;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.json.RooJson;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJson
public class Doctor {

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
    private Set<DoctorMessages> DoctorMessages = new HashSet<DoctorMessages>();

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
    private Set<DoctorNotifications> DoctorNotifications = new HashSet<DoctorNotifications>();

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
    private Set<DoctorDiagnosis> DoctorDiagnosis = new HashSet<DoctorDiagnosis>();

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int doctorID;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8)
    private String Password;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String UserName;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String FirstName;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String LastName;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String Specialty;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String status;

    /**
     */
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
    private Set<Careteam> attendingpatients = new HashSet<Careteam>();
}
```

Patient.java

```
package com.medroid.domain;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.json.RooJson;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJson
public class Patient {

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<PatientMessages> PatientMessages = new HashSet<PatientMessages>();

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<PatientNotifications> PatientNotifications = new HashSet<PatientNotifications>();

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<PatientMedications> PatientMedications = new HashSet<PatientMedications>();

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<PatientAllergies> PatientAllergies = new HashSet<PatientAllergies>();

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<DoctorDiagnosis> Diagnosis = new HashSet<DoctorDiagnosis>();

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int patientID;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String UserName;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8)
    private String Password;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String FirstName;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String LastName;

    /**
     */
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String MiddleName;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Max(120L)
    private int Age;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String Sex;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String DOB;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String City;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String Prov;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String Bloodtype;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String Status;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String HC;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String SymptomDesc;

    /**
     */
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient")
    private Set<Careteam > AttendingDoctors = new HashSet<Careteam>();
}
```

I created a new controller called JSONPatientDoctors and wrapped the controller with a web mvc controller so I will hook into my views.

JsonPatientDoctors.java

```
package com.medroid.domain;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.runner.Request;
import com.medroid.domain.Careteam;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@RequestMapping("/jsonpatientdoctors/**")
@Controller
public class JsonPatientDoctors {



    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "{id}")
    public void post(@PathVariable Long id, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/jsonpatientdoctors/GETPATIENTS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void GET() {

/*    List<Careteam> result = Careteam.findAllCareteams();
        System.out.println(result.get(0));*/
        /*"SELECT o FROM Careteam o"*/
        List<Careteam> careteam = Careteam.entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Careteam o where o.patient = '1'", Careteam.class).getResultList();
/*      List<Careteam> careteam = Careteam.findAllCareteams(sortFieldName, sortOrder)*/
        System.out.println(careteam.get(0));
    }


    @RequestMapping
    public String index() {
        return "jsonpatientdoctors/index";
    }
}
```

I was able to pull the patient data by ID but the issue is I want to only select the doctor field where the patient ID = whatever,

I tried "SELECT o.doctor FROM Careteam o where o.patient = '1'"

But I get an error:

Type specified for TypedQuery [com.medroid.domain.Careteam] is incompatible with query return type [class com.medroid.domain.Doctor]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [com.medroid.domain.Careteam] is incompatible with query return type [class com.medroid.domain.Doctor]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, here is the solution

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/jsonpatientdoctors/GetDoctorsByPatientID/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> showJson(@PathVariable("id") String id) { 
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    try {
    String ID = id;
    ArrayList<String> DoctorJson = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<Careteam> careteam = Careteam.entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Careteam o where o.patient =" + ID, Careteam.class).getResultList();


        if (careteam == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }


       for(int i=0; i < careteam.size(); i++){
           DoctorJson.add(careteam.get(i).getDoctor().toJson());
        }


        return new ResponseEntity<String>(DoctorJson.toString(),headers,HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"ERROR\":"+e.getMessage()+"\"}", headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```